# Zend Framework is not using layout.phtml file version 1.11.11

Tags: zend-framework

I have created `layout.phtml` file and placed the code for header, footer and to include the code for views. but it is just showing html of actions only the layout file is not being used by the zend.

I also mention the path of my layout file in `application.ini` file.

the layout file is placed here

```
application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml
```

The application.ini contains following for layout

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
```

What could be the possible reason?

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled the layout in this project? I mean...using the command "zf enable layout"

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: No, I did not used any command yet. Some how I am unable to execute that commands. I have to do on my own basis

Comment: You typically need two `application.ini` references to enable layouts. One is the path reference you already have. The other is `resources.layout.layout = "layout"`, a pointer to your `layout.phtml` file. Do you have that, too?

Comment: @DavidWeinraub `layout` is the default anyway and is not required

Comment: @Daric Can you show an example action method that isn't working as expected?

Comment: @Phil Yep, you're right. Guess I never realized that since I typically have both references in `application.ini`. Thanks!

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa, Phil: Thanks to both of you. I executed the command and now working fine.

Comment: Glad to help you. Write the answer and accept it for future users ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using XAMPP by any chance? If this is the case, run `zf show version`. If this does not correspond to the version you have just installed, open `xampp\php\PEAR` and see if there is an old `Zend` folder. If so, you can either remove contents or just replace `zf.bat` and `zf.php` with the ones in `bin` (on the new copy that you have downloaded).

Remember: All this is ONLY applicable if you use XAMPP server.

====

Another solution that worked for me was:

In Windows CMD, I changes the path to my project directory and tried the command again and it worked. I used: `cd c:\xampp\htdocs\zend`where

```
C:\ ----- C-Drive
xampp --- Where I installed xampp
htdocs -- Xampp Server's public folder
zend ---- My project is store here
```

After that. I ran `zf enable layout`

And it worked. Sorry if you are not using Xampp.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `zf enable layout` command with xammp in windows Command prompt. Just copy the url to your project directory for eg: `C:\xampp\htdocs\my project` then

- go to cmd
- type :cd\
- then type :cd C:\xampp\htdocs\my project(just paste it) then press enter
- then type :zf enable layout

it works